# Detect whether the 3gb Switch is on or off programmatically

Tags: c, winapi

I've been trying to determine whether the 3GB switch is on or off on the system my program is running by calling GetSystemInfo() and checking lpMaximumApplicationAddress on the SYSTEM_INFO struct.

No luck. I think I am doing something wrong.

How do you check whether the 3GB switch is on or not on Windows in C?
Code is appreciated.

thanks

Comment: lpMaximumApplicationAddress is the right thing to check. What is returned when you try it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your program is compiled as large address aware, you could simply call [`GlobalMemoryStatusEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366589%28VS.85%29.aspx) and check the `ullTotalVirtual` field.  If it's larger than 2GB, and you're running on a 32-bit system, then the 3GB flag must be turned on.

I actually have no idea how to 'properly' tell if Windows is natively 32 or 64 bit, but if you have a 32-bit process you could call [`IsWow64Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684139%28VS.85%29.aspx) to see if you're running on a 64-bit OS.

This all seems a bit indirect, I know :)

Comment: A 64-bit OS would report 4GB (minus 128k at the start and 128k at the end) for ``ullTotalVirtual``. Really if ``ullTotalVirtual`` is bigger than 3 GB, then you know it's an x64 OS.

Answer (score 3):

Is your program IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE ?

http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/platform/server/PAE/PAEmem.mspx

> Executables that can use the 3-GB address space are required to have the bit IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE set in their image header. If you are the developer of the executable, you can specify a linker flag (/LARGEADDRESSAWARE).

Comment: I just need to know whether it's on or not. that's all

Comment: The program you use to test whether it's on must be built /LARGEADDRESSAWARE.  is it?

Comment: thanks.
I'll ask again: Is there a way to know whether the 3gb switch is ON  or OFF by code? If yes, do you know how to do this? regardless of whether that flag is set.

Comment: @Jessica: I think John is trying to tell you that Windows will lie to your application unless the `IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE` bit is set in the executable.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, I've been able to do the detection using the following code (found [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/microsoft/Win32-Kernel/30018488/detect-3gb-switch-programmatically.aspx)) :

```
if (!isWow64())
{
  BOOL b3GBSwitch = FALSE;
  SYSTEM_INFO siSysInfo;
  GetSystemInfo(&siSysInfo);
  b3GBSwitch = ((DWORD)siSysInfo.lpMaximumApplicationAddress & 0x80000000) != 0;
  printf("3GB Switch Enabled: %d\n", b3GBSwitch );
}
```

The code is executed in a process that is *not* LARGEADDRESSAWARE.

So far I've been able to test on Xp x86, Vista x86 and Seven x64.